# Drop all words with two or less letters from string, except for the word "no" Python

Tags: python, regex, string

Title is pretty self-explanatory: in my language most three-or-less letter words don't add value to the text, except for the word "no" that may change the meaning of a sentence completely.

I can drop all words with 3 or less letters doing the following:

```
shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b')
df.text=df.text.apply(lambda x: shortword.sub('', x) )
```

I just need to input some conditional statement to leave the word "no" out, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your regexp matches words with 3 or less letters, not 2 or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\W*\b(?!no)\w{1,2}\b'
       ^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!no)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there cannot be `no` char sequence
- `\w{1,2}` - 1 or 2 word chars (if you need to only match *letter* words, use `[^\W\d_]{1,2}` instead)
- `\b` - a word boundary

Also, you may use `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'\W*\b(?!no)\w{1,2}\b', '')` to perform a search and replace operation on a single column.

Comment: Thank you very much! worked exactly as intended. I should improve my regex skills, as it seems